# Assistance targeting URL with window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seeking assistance with the window.location object.

In the markup I'm working with, there are two tabs (LIs), one for the search results 'list' view, the other for 'map' view, and a graphical element that, when clicked, should trigger the Map View tab/URL (Google Maps).

The map view has a dynamic URL based on user search criteria, which is the URL I want to load when the image is clicked.

Here's my watered-down markup:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="next"><a href="#">List View</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Map View</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the script I've written:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery){

  jQuery('.nav-tabs li:eq(0)').addClass('firstTab');
  jQuery('.nav-tabs li:eq(1)').addClass('secondTab');

  //add background color to visually focus tab
  jQuery('.active.firstTab', '.active.secondTab').css({
    'background-color': '#fff'
  });

  //insert content banner after second search result
  jQuery('.resRow:eq(1)').after('<div id="contentBanner"><a href=""><img src="http://prodcache.internal.ihg.com/content/dam/etc/media_library/branded/6c/en/us/banners/map/map_promo.gif" alt="Click here to view map location"></a></div>');


  // Fire click on the element that has the <a> with the proper 'href' attribute
  var tab = window.location.hash;

  $("#contentBanner:has(a[href=" + tab + "])").click();

  //remove/add class names
  jQuery('#contentBanner a').click(function() {
    jQuery('.nav.nav-tabs li:eq(0)').removeClass().addClass('next firstTab');
    jQuery('.nav.nav-tabs li:eq(1)').removeClass().addClass('active secondTab');
  });

  console.log("Search Map: Variant 4");        

});
```

Any assistance/directon you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: Yeah, this is very vague. What is the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I am guessing you need it to be window.location.pathname + window.location.hash instead of just hash

Comment: Why don't you pass `$` argument as: `function ($)` instead of `jQuery`  ? Might save your fingers later ;)

Comment: By default, the List View tab is active, as intended. However, I need the Map View tab to be triggered when a particular graphic is clicked, but it should also load the view of Google Maps based on the search criteria. The way I have it coded now, clicking the graphic loads the current URL.

Comment: By the way, I consider myself an uber-noob when it comes to JS. So it may take me a while to digest any suggestions being made.